# Explanation on the limitation of the proof of the Law of Cosines

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

Regarding this method of proving the Law of Cosine:
[image: Screenshot taken from https://brilliant.org/wiki/cosine-rule/]

It is noted on that page that

> This proof isn't perfect. We should have been worried about angles. This can be avoided by using directed angles.

I don't understand why we need to worry about the angles, as throughout high school, I have always been treating both the angles and the lengths of the sides as scalar quantities.

Comment: I would guess this is because the proof doesn't explain why the formula holds for obtuse angles in a triangle.

Comment: @A-levelStudent Hi, thanks for answering! However, I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean: in my opinion, if we imagine Angle B in the diagram as an obtuse angle, we can still prove Cosine Rule using the above method. Thus, I am not entirely sure, what you mean by this method doesn't explain why the formula holds for obtuse angles.

Comment: @A-levelStudent Thanks for following up! I don't think such a triangle exists, at least in Euclidean geometry... Are you referring to any other types of geometry by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote is nonsense, ignore it. My point is that for the angle which is obtuse, the above proof must be altered. Eg if as in the proof you're proving it for cosA and A is obtuse, the proof must be altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\pi/2 < \alpha < \pi$, we have an obtuse angle at $A$ and we must consider the geometry of the figure accordingly.

The altitude $h$ from $B$ to $AC$ is no longer "inside" the triangle.  It extends to some point, say $B'$, on the line containing $AC$ such that $|B'C| > |AC|$; in other words, the signed distance $r$ would need to be negative and $b-r > b$.  That said, the relationship $$r = c \cos \alpha$$ does take this into account, since when $\pi/2 < \alpha < \pi$, $-1 < \cos \alpha < 0$, consequently $-c < r < 0$.

You can also see this in the final identity $$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos \alpha,$$ since again, when $\cos \alpha < 0$, the RHS exceeds $b^2 + c^2$, which is what we would have if $\alpha$ were a right angle.  If we think of $b$ and $c$ as fixed and $\alpha$ allowed to vary continuously from $0$ to $\pi$, you would find that the length of $a$ increases from $0$ to $b+c$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! If possible, could you elaborate on what you meant by b-r>b? I don't quite understand why does this inequality hold true since it seems to me that it should be b-r<b. Thanks!

Comment: @wl_ If you draw an obtuse triangle with obtuse angle at $A$, and drop the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$, you'll see you have to extend $AC$ to do it.  Then $r$ is no longer "inside" $AC$ and the distance $r = AB'$ would need to be negative for the proof to make sense.